# Items change position after tab being changed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I ran into a problem while programming on the new Xcode 5 and iOS 7.

The App is basically some `ViewControllers` showing different information and they are linked with a `TabBarController`.

Now, the problem is, that whenever I compile, at first the initial view appears as it should, but when I switch to another tab and go back the view changes.

I have set up the constraints so that the lower part should stick to the bottom and the `MapView` changes height according to the screen size.